# mdframed in a itemize environment

Tags: itemize, mdframed

I would like to have a `mdframed` environment of with the same width when it is used in the normal body of my document and when it is used in an `itemize` environment.

Is it possible?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}

\newmdenv[%
leftmargin = 2cm,
rightmargin = 2cm,
middlelinewidth = 0.3mm,
align=center,
backgroundcolor = lightgray]
{myframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}
Test 1
\end{myframe}

\begin{itemize}
\item This is some text

\begin{myframe}
Test 2
\end{myframe}

But I would like, if possible, the two framed to have the same size, and also to aligned, even if one is in an \verb+itemize+ environment.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post a minimal code showing your problem?

Comment: Possibly {\leftskip=0pt  ...}.  Can't test it without an MWE.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have added a MWE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use tcolorbox. It behaves much better than mdframed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox
{myframe}
{left skip = 2cm-\csname @totalleftmargin\endcsname,
right skip = 2cm,
}

\begin{document}
blblblbb

\begin{myframe}
Test 1
\end{myframe}

\begin{itemize}
\item This is some text 

\begin{myframe}
Test 2
\end{myframe}

But I would like, if possible, the two framed to have the same size, and also to aligned, even if one is in an \verb+itemize+ environment.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ulrike. Do you mean `tcolorbox` is better generally (according to you)? Or just in this case?

Comment: In general. It is more powerful, works better, is actively maintained.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{}` to adjust the `leftmargin=` when you are within an `itemize` environment:

[image]

### Notes:

- I removed the `align=center` option as you can't have the frame centered with the `\linewidth` *and* also be aligned on both margins when the `\linewdith` is altered (as it is within the `itemize` environment).

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc,showframe}

\newlength{\MyLeftMargin}
\setlength{\MyLeftMargin}{\leftmargin}
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{%
    \setlength{\MyLeftMargin}{0cm}%
}

\newmdenv[%
leftmargin = \MyLeftMargin,
rightmargin = \leftmargin,
middlelinewidth = 0.3mm,
%align=center,
backgroundcolor = lightgray,
]
{myframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}
Test 1 
\end{myframe}

\begin{itemize}
\item This is some text 

\begin{myframe}
Test 2 
\end{myframe}

But I would like, if possible, the two framed to have the same size, and also to aligned, even if one is in an \verb+itemize+ environment.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```